# ProgressDialog Problem?

Tags: java, android, progress-bar

There is a ProgressDialog in my app. It is running but after finishing process does not close. Where is the error, I'm doing.
Thanks.

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {     
        public void onClick(View v) {            

                progressdialog.show();

                 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {                           

                                 // doing something...  

                                progressdialog.dismiss();

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }).start();         
            }                  
    });
```

Comment: You are trying to dismiss a UI element from outside the Main thread?

Comment: I'm doing a web service process and filling a list in Thread. Then visible some element.

Answer (score 1):

do this......

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {     
        public void onClick(View v) {            

                progressdialog.show();

                 new Thread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            try {                           

                                 // doing something...  

                               hm.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    }).start();         
            }                  
    });


    Handler hm = new Handler()
    {
       public void handleMessage(Message msg)
       {

         progressdialog.dismiss();
        }


    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

progressdialog.setVisible(false);

if pricessdialog instanse of JDialog

Comment: oh, didn't notice. is that swt? my solution is for swing

Answer (score 0):

The process dialog can also be dismissed by calling following method.

```
progressdialog.cancel();
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `progressdialog.dismiss();` from the main thread;

Answer (score 0):

The right way of doing any work in background while showing the progress dialog is using AsyncTask with ProgressDialog bounded. See [here](http://it-projects.spb.ru/?p=150&lang=en). Remember, that you can not modify the UI from the thread, which is not UI thread.

Comment: I'm doing in Thread following process:

    ((ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView)).setAdapter(adapter); 

and gives me the following error:

    android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

any suggestion?

Comment: The platform already told you what you should know: you modify the UI from non the UI thread. Use special class for that, like AsyncTask, or use Handlers. Google them a bit.